# Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.grid.Panel - How to add it?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to create a simple grid in my sencha project that extends 'Ext.grid.Panel'.

When I make from sencha cmd the "sencha app build" command, I have the exception: "Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.grid.Panel".

Actually I don't have it in my sencha folder, so how can I add it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can run the gridpanel from your dev folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I undestood your question correctly, but I cannot use anything concerning Ext.grid.*

Comment: Ahh. Good. I was not sure if you could not use it in a build or never. Ok. There are reasons, why it is only part of ExtJS and not Sencha Touch. Grids (my personal opinion) do not make sense in ST. Why not use a list (or dataview) and use a good itemTpl to create such a grid. If you need to be able to click sections of the item you can grab them from the itemtap event. the event.target.className.indexOf("XXX") can help you at that point. By changing the recordset and an tpl@if you can get a great user experience.

Comment: Fantastic suggestion, I'm going to try and I let you know. Thanks a lot for your availability, you are very friendly and knowledgeable, the best for a newbie as me.

Comment: You can always upvote a comment to help other to notify a helpful comment ;)

Comment: I know but I cannot update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this inside the app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AppName',

    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ]
...
```

Comment: I already put it in the App.js, but I get the same exception; the problem is that I don't have any "grid" folder with Panel.js file within my touch/src folder. Is possible to add it?

Comment: Yes you can add them to touch.src. But I would probably grab them from the api documentation instead of mixing ExtJS with Sencha Touch

Comment: Totally agree, but I still don't understand how to use it without integrate...maybe am I missing something in the init-impl.xml?

Comment: Simply add them to the touch.src folder. Then add them to the requires part in app.js. While you run 'sencha app build' or 'sencha app refresh' the bootstrap.js will be updated and include these files later inside the build app.js   Nothing else for you to do.

Comment: But as you said, it could be a mess if I mix ExtJs libraries with ST plugin...in any case, for the future, if I would add an external libraries, do I have to download and add(like a jar)? could you suggest a trustable mirror for ExtJs libriries?  Or it's enough to define somewhere the dependency and the sencha app build download it for me(like Maven..)? Thanks again

Comment: I would go to the API docs for Sencha Touch. There is a grid documentation, and you could "view source". If these are the same as for ExtJS I would copy the ExtJS library otherwise it might be a bit more work to copy these sources one by one ;)